# Async function in wit actions

Tags: node.js, asynchronous, callback, wit.ai

I am currently developing a bot using `wit.ai`. I am quite new to `node.js`. Basically, I am following the guide provided by `node-wit` lib. I construct my `wit` object by:

```
const wit = new Wit({
  accessToken: WIT_TOKEN,
  actions,
  logger: new log.Logger(log.INFO)
});
```

In my actions, I have something like:

```
const actions = {
  send({sessionId}, {text}) {
     //my sending action goes here.
  },
  firstaction({context, entities,sessionId}) {
    var data = async_function();
    context.receiver = data;
    return context;
 }
}
```

The issue is that whatever comes after `async_function` will be executed first. I tried to let `async_function` return a promise. However, this wouldn't work since whatever comes after my first action in `node-wit` library will be executed first without waiting for the context to return. I don't want to modify the `node-wit` library.

Any idea that would solve my issue is appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use async library for asynchronous call

https://caolan.github.io/async/docs.html

```
const async = require('async')

const actions = {
  send({sessionId}, {text}) {
    //my sending action goes here.
  },
firstaction({context, entities,sessionId}) {
   async.waterfall([function(callback) {
    var d = async_function();
    // if err pass it to callback first parameter
    // return callback(err)
    callback(null,d);
 }], function(err, result) {
      if(err) {
         return err;
       }
      var data = result;
      context.receiver = data;
      return context;
   })
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your reference! I am just wondering if the function calling my firstaction is going to wait for the waterfall to finish?

Comment: I am quite not sure about how your code is running, `firstaction()` is a function call and you are returning context?
could you please post `firstaction()` function definition, and `async_function()` definition too.

Comment: Yes, the firstaction() is a function call that is returning context. Anyway, I solved it by using your way. It requires a bit restructure of my code tho. Thank you so much!.

Comment: That's Great Bro! #happyCoding